# -bash: /shared/conda/bin/python3: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

Here's the python3 & python executables which should be picked up by bash

```
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

However upon running python3 it checks for conda python

```
$ python3 setup.py installcli
-bash: /shared/conda/bin/python3: No such file or directory
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: What does `type -a python3` show?

Comment: ```type -a python3
python3 is /usr/bin/python3```

Comment: `installcli` does not sound like a standard subcommand for `setup.py`. Where does that come from? I wonder if something that is doing under the hood is giving you grief.

Comment: Does `/usr/bin/python3 setup.py installcli` give the same error?

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat: Perhaps a broken symlink?